Basic properties of the Whitehead product
I am reading through the text Homotopical Topology by Fomenko and Fuchs. On page 128, there are the following exercises regarding the Whitehead product:

Now, this looks different from the other sources that I can find where the graded symmetry is supposed to be $[\beta,\alpha]=(-1)^{mn}[\alpha,\beta]$. I thought this is most likely due to some discrepancy in the definitions but I can spot none.
Even worse, I somehow managed to shown the identity in the book before I looked at other sources... From what I did, the problem boils down to finding the degree of the mapping $S^{n+m-1}\to S^{n+m-1}$ that interchanges the first $n$ and the last $m$ coordinate. I pulled back on the volume form $\sum(-1)^{i+1}x^idx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}$ and found there to be a coefficient of $(-1)^{(n-1)m+n}$. Now I really doubt my proof.
Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you!
Edit: Here is the definition in the text (an obvious typo: $t$ should be $f$)

From what I understand, this agrees with the wikipedia definition at least.
I will also present my proof. $[\alpha,\beta]$ is represented by composition $S^{n+m-1}\xrightarrow{w} S^n\wedge S^m\xrightarrow{\alpha\wedge\beta}X$ which is the same as $S^{n+m-1}\xrightarrow{T} S^{n+m-1}\xrightarrow{w'}S^m\wedge S^n\xrightarrow{\beta\wedge\alpha} X$ where $T$ interchanges the $n$ and $m$ coordinates. Consider the volume form $\omega=\sum(-1)^{i+1}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}$, I found out $T^*\omega=(-1)^{nm+n+m}\omega$. For example, if $1\leq i\leq n$
$$\begin{align*}
&T^*((-1)^{i+1}x^idx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m})\\=&(-1)^{i+1}x^{n+i}dx^{n+1}\wedge\dots\widehat{dx^{n+i}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}\wedge dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^m\\
=&(-1)^{i+1}x^{n+i}(-1)^{(n-1)m}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^{n+i}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}\\
=&(-1)^{n+i+1}x^{n+i}(-1)^{(n-1)m+n}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^{n+i}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}
\end{align*}$$

Could you include some definitions and more context in your post? What kind of object is $\alpha$, how is $[\cdot,\cdot\cdot]$ defined? Where is your proof?

The sign depends on your degree conventions and perhaps different sources are using different ones; it depends on whether you think of an element of $\pi_n(X)$ as living in degree $n$ or $n-1$ (since it is "really" an element of $\pi_{n-1}(\Omega X)$ and this is used to define the Whitehead bracket).

I have included the definition in the textbook, it does seem to agree with the one on wikipedia.

The sign $(-1)^{mn + m + n}$ appearing in Exercise $4$ should be $(-1)^{mn}$.

I will also present my proof. $[\alpha,\beta]$ is represented by composition $S^{n+m-1}\xrightarrow{w} S^n\color{red}{\vee} S^m\xrightarrow{\alpha\color{red}{\vee}\beta}X$ which is the same as $S^{n+m-1}\xrightarrow{T} S^{n+m-1}\xrightarrow{w'}S^m\color{red}{\vee} S^n\xrightarrow{\beta\color{red}{\vee}\alpha} X$ where $T$ interchanges the $n$ and $m$ coordinates. Consider the volume form $\omega=\sum(-1)^{i+1}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}$, I found out $T^*\omega=(-1)^{\color{blue}{nm+n+m}}\omega$. For example, if $1\leq i\leq \color{red}{m}$
$$\begin{align*}
&T^*((-1)^{i+1}x^idx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m})\\=&(-1)^{i+1}x^{n+i}dx^{n+1}\wedge\dots\widehat{dx^{n+i}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}\wedge dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^\color{red}{n}\\
=&(-1)^{i+1}x^{n+i}(-1)^{\color{red}{(m-1)n}}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^{n+i}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}\\
=&(-1)^{n+i+1}x^{n+i}(-1)^{\color{red}{(m-1)n+n}}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^{n+i}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{n+m}
\end{align*}$$

There were some typos and errors your in calculation, which I've corrected in red above. In the last step, you originally had a sign $(-1)^{(n-1)m + n}$ which is the same as $(-1)^{mn + m + n}$. However, notice the correct sign in the last step is $(-1)^{(m-1)n + n}$, which is certainly $(-1)^{mn}$. In case $m + 1 \le i \le m+n$ a sign $(-1)^{(n-1)m + m}$ comes out, which again is $(-1)^{mn}$. So the expression in blue should be $mn$.
Thus $[\alpha, \beta] = (-1)^{\color{red}{mn}}[\beta, \alpha]$, which matches the graded symmetry property in wiki.

Oh wow I was very not careful when dealing with the indices, thank you so much!
